# How to use integers to display a status

Tags: android

I found something interesting in the android OS, that I want to use in my own apps but how?

Like in the ConnectivityManager http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html, you see status codes like

```
public static int TYPE_WIFI = 1;
```

When you call the connectivity manager with this code:

```
ConnectivityManager mConnectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Connectivity_Service);
NetworkInfo iswifi = mConnectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
if (iswifi.isConnected()){ msg = "You got WIFI!"}
```

but if I'm having a class that needs to say if I'm having a internet connection, how can i let it return a status code like that?

Already thanks for your answers!:)

Wout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the simple version:

```
/*@return boolean return true if the application can access the internet*/
public static boolean haveInternet(Context context){
    NetworkInfo info = ((ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (info==null || !info.isConnected()) {
        return false;
    }
    if (info.isRoaming()) {
        // here is the roaming option you can change it if you want to disable internet while roaming, just return false
        return true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

---

Here you have it with preferences for wifi, you can specify if you want some actions to be limited by a preference set to only use wifi. 
For example you can check for small downloads using withRoamingPref = false; returning true for any internet connection.
Then check for large downloads using withRoamingPref = true, in this case, it will check if the user has enabled "only wifi" to download them and returns true if using wifi or true if the user allows the mobile connection to download them, returning false if there is no internet connection or if you are on mobile connection and the user has disabled it to download heavy files.

```
public static boolean haveInternet(Context context, boolean withRoamingPref){
    NetworkInfo info = ((ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (info==null || !info.isConnected()) {
        return false;
    }
    if (info.isRoaming()) {
        // here is the roaming option you can change it if you want to disable internet while roaming, just return false
        if(withRoamingPref) {
            SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
            boolean onlyWifi = settings.getBoolean("onlyWifi", false);

            if (onlyWifi) {
                return false;

            }else{
                return true;
            }

        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

---

Modified case to return all three states and decide how to act on another piece of the application:

```
/*@return int return 0 if the application can't access the internet
    return 1 if on mobile data or 2 if using wifi connection*/
public static int haveInternet(Context context){
    NetworkInfo info = ((ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (info==null || !info.isConnected()) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (info.isRoaming()) {
        return 1;
    }else{
        return 2;
    }
}
```

PS: Instead of the numbers you should assign each state with a static int and then return that instead of the raw int. For example, declare at the start of the class:

public static int INTERNET_DISABLED = 0;

then instead of "return 0;" you'll use "return INTERNET_DISABLED;"

this way you don't have to remember what means each number, you'll check in other segment of the app against the names as in:

```
if(myClass.haveInternet == myClass.INTERNET_DISABLED){
     //TODO show no internet message
}
```

Comment: in my application I need to know things like does the user is connected through mobile data, because I can let him download only the small things, and limit the big files for wifi only. And give an error when there is no connection available

Comment: Roaming means that the phone is connected through mobile data, so you have that covered, the second code snipet is what I use for that purpose, I'll reword the explanation. but you could change the boolean to int and return 0 for no connection, 1 for mobile data and 2 for wifi connection.

Comment: Also check my last edit, I think that's what you're looking for, I somehow overlooked the title of your question when answering, if you need more help on how to manage and use the static int variables, ask away.

Comment: yes your last edit was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Create a Network Checker class as :

```
public class NetWorkCheck{
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager;
    NetworkInfo iswifi,mobileInfo;

    public String checkNow(Context con){

        try{
            connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) 
                             con.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            iswifi  = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(
                                          ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
            mobileInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(
                                        ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
        if(wifiInfo.isConnected())
            return "You got WIFI!";
        else {
               if( mobileInfo.isConnected()){
                return "You got TYPE_MOBILE!";
               }
               {
                 return "WIFI or TYPE_MOBILE Connectivity Problem!";
               }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            return "CheckConnectivity Exception";
        }
    }
}
```

In Activities you can use this class for checking wifi as:

```
NetWorkCheck ntw = new NetWorkCheck();
String meg_wifi = ntw.checkNow(getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: I want the application returning a status when it is called, so when I do: ntw.checkNow(TYPE_WIFI); it returns me if I have WiFi or not, but the same with MOBILE_DATA and NO_CONNECTIVITY

Comment: But how does this work for the other connectivity things int the ConnectivityManager class? http://whdeveloper.host22.com/stackoverflow.html this is the code I have at this moment but I need to make it working. So I want something like a check "getconnection();" and it returns the status int for the connection

Comment: why you are extending Activity in InternetAcces class?

Comment: So I can use `getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);'`

Comment: no this is not right way for Creating an global class for checking network connection. just pass context to class constructor or method for accessing `getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);` as in my answer see `String meg_wifi = ntw.checkNow(getApplicationContext());' here i'm passing getApplicationContext() to checkNow for getting current context

Comment: Here's a warning , if some WiFi only tablets [specifically the galaxy note 10.1 , not sure about the rest] crashes when you check for data connectivity [wifi checking is fine , but type mobile checking crashes] so keep that in mind

Comment: I'm really a beginner at programming so I didn't think of that in the first place, but I have changed that now, thanks for the tip:)